# why is continuing android keyboard after than memo max length in firemonkey android app?

Tags: android, delphi, keyboard, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

why is continuing android keyboard after than memo max length?

My Memo max length 120 characters but android keyboard is continuing.

How does android keyboard finish input after than memo max length?

Note: delphi firemonkey android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FireMonkey **does not** use platform-native UI controls (if you want that, have a look at the [Delphi Android Native Components](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiandroid/) library).  Every UI control is custom-written in Delphi to run (fairly) consistent on multiple platforms. `TMemo` does not utilize Android's native [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) control. The `TMemo.MaxLength` property is only meaningful within FireMonkey itself (while the control is receiving keystrokes, when text is pasted from the clipboard, etc).  Android has no concept of the `TMemo.MaxLength` property, and there is no way to tell Android what the `MaxLength` is set to.

Comment: did you worked with `Delphi Android Native Components` ? is it working with 10.1?